# truffle solc specific compiler fail

Tags: truffle, solc, truffle-compile

,/C/Users/juhne/ipfs-image-dapp/contracts/Migrations.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
^----------------------^

Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.4.24".
Please update your truffle config or pragma statement(s).
(See https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#compiler-configuration for information on
configuring Truffle to use a specific solc compiler version.)

i change the specific version in truffle.js but the error still show i using 0.5.16 version...

compiler:{
solc :{
version : " 0.4.20"
}
},

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question to "[Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16, but one or more of your contracts specify “pragma solidity ^0.8.0”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68070253/error-truffle-is-currently-using-solc-0-5-16-but-one-or-more-of-your-contracts)"

Answer (score 1):

You may be using two truffle config  files like `truffle.js` and `truffle-config.js` if so, delete one of them